# delete special characters from a text file after the first element in r

Tags: r, text-editor

I am trying to read a text file using `read.table()` in R. R does not read anything that follows a `#`.  However, there are pound symbols in the text that have nothing to do with the comments.  I want to delete the unwanted `#` symbols without adding the comments to the data frame.

Fortunately, all of the pound symbols that I want to keep are in the first element of each row.  So basically I need to delete all `#` symbols that are not in the first element of the row.

```
2018-08-14 00:00:42 102.18.18.2  
2018-08-15 00:00:47 223.45.67.8    
2018-08-15 00:00:48 026.15.65.0    
2018-08-15 00:00:49 924.43.47.0    
2018-08-15 00:00:49 122.45.#67.9
```

I want to keep the pound symbol in the first line and delete the pound symbol in the last line that is causing problems in the data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a feature in Regular Expression knows as capture groups.

Just open your file in an editor which supports finding text using RegEx, such as VS Code.

In the Find box, write: (.+)(#)

In the replace box, write: $1

Clicking Replace all should remove all your # characters in between texts.

Alternatively, you could also write a script to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible pure R solution:

### MWE

First let's make your problem a full MWE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
cat(
'#2018-08-14 00:00:42 102.18.18.2',
'2018-08-14 00:00:42 102.18.18.2',  
'2018-08-15 00:00:47 223.45.67.8',    
'2018-08-15 00:00:48 026.15.65.0',    
'2018-08-15 00:00:49 924.43.47.0',    
'2018-08-15 00:00:49 122.45.#67.9', sep = '\n', file = 'mytable.txt')
```

This creates a file in your working directory that we can read in.

### Solution

```
(x <- readLines('mytable.txt')) 
(y <- gsub('(?<!^)#', '', x, perl = TRUE))
read.table(text = y)

##           V1       V2          V3
## 1 2018-08-14 00:00:42 102.18.18.2
## 2 2018-08-15 00:00:47 223.45.67.8
## 3 2018-08-15 00:00:48 026.15.65.0
## 4 2018-08-15 00:00:49 924.43.47.0
## 5 2018-08-15 00:00:49 122.45.67.9
```

I wrapped each line with `()` so you can see the out put.  In real application I wouldn't include them.

The magic happens with `gsub('(?<!^)#', '', x, perl = TRUE)` line.  It uses a Negative Lookbehind (https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) of `(?<!^)#` and can be read as:

- `#` (any pound sign) BUT
- `?` (what) `<` (comes before)
- `!` (is not)
- `^` (the begininning of the line)